# Websphere Commerce 7 Customize service call

Tags: java, websphere, commerce

Websphere commerce 7 Madison Store.
I am trying to change the view, after calling the orderadditem.
In madison click on addto cart in any item it will call AjaxOrderItemAdd service.
But after adding i need to change the view from struts-config-ext.xml.

Uptill what i have done is .
created a command MyOrderItemAddCmdImpl

```
public void performExecute() throws ECException {
        super.performExecute();
        responseProperties.put(ECConstants.EC_VIEWTASKNAME, "CustomView");
        setResponseProperties(responseProperties);
    }
```

and added entry in cmdreg table

```
update cmdreg set classname='com.mindtree.cust.MyOrderItemAddCmdImpl' where interfacename=   'com.ibm.commerce.orderitems.commands.OrderItemAddCmd';
```

and added a custom view in struts-confid-ext.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your CustomView as an URL parameter in the AjaxOrderItemAdd method.

Please refer to

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/refs/rosorderitemadd.htm

for more details.